# How do I change a string of double numbers with spaces to an array of just doubles that I can work with

Tags: java, android

I am new to coding, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have a text file on an android phone that holds several blocks of strings that are basically numbers - "553955765.50    272 272 272 200.1   100 7391    22  22  10  53"

I've managed to read the file from the phone but every time I try to convert this string of numbers into an array of doubles, I get an error saying

java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "553955765.50  272 272 272 200.1   100 7391    22  22  10  53"

Here is my block of code; any help would be greatly appreciated - again I am very new to coding, so if you could explain the solution, I would be eternally grateful!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard, "test.txt");

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            double[] ary = new double[tokens.length];
            for (int n = 0; n < tokens.length; n++){

                ary[n] = Double.parseDouble(tokens[n]);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    //Find the view by its id
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

//Set the text
    tv.setText(text.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the full error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: usd.read_text, PID: 32434                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{usd.read_text/usd.read_text.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "553955765.50    272 272 272 200.1   100 7391    22  22  10  53"

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "553955765.50   272 272 272 200.1   100 7391    22  22  10  53"
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
at usd.read_text.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: Looks like you are doing fine. Where is the issue

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue using this code with the given input string. Is that the actual error? If not, please post the actual error in its entirety. While you do that, make sure you aren't trying to parse any empty strings and make sure the file is actually separating the digits by a space and not tabs or something.

Comment: A) dont ignore IO exceptions. B) the message is pretty clear "1 2 3" can't be parsed as single number. Something is fishy about the code you are showing here ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that every number after a space is a double, you must use `split()` to separate the numbers in an array of strings. After That, you use the Double.parseDouble() in every item of the array generated by split().